# Can we visualize the performance of JMS or EMS by integrating to datadog?

Tags: datadog, tibco-ems

We are using JMS (tibco EMS) as messaging service can We visualize the performance using Datadog?
If it is not possible do we have any alternate?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Prometheus endpoint for Tibco EMS:

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/statistics-logger-tibco-enterprise-message-service#toc-15

I think you can then add the prometheus integration to your datadog agent to send the data do datadog, and build your own dashboard for that:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/prometheus/#data-collected

Comment: Direct integration with JMS with Data dog is not possible?

Comment: JMS is an API, not a protocol. All vendors implement it in their own way, so you always need a vendor-specific driver for any integration.